# Convert String Array into Different String

Tags: c#, arrays, string

So I will give the scenario first.
I have some values in a string array ( less than 10). I want to pass these values into 10 different strings.
Say if I get 7 values in the array, String 1 to string 7 will have the values  to 7 respectively and string 8,9 and 10 will be null/blank.

Can anyone help in how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not really get you problem here. Did you try anything? Please show us some code

Comment: Why not create an empty array with a length of 10, then populate that array later. With 7 [0 - 6] the remaining 3 indexes will be null...

Comment: "String 1 to string 7" - in .NET we usually use 0-bases for vectors / arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't often recommended but there are some valid scenarios for splitting arrays to multiple variables in the way you describe and here is an example of the code you need:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] stringArray = {"cat", "dog", "bird", "elephant", "frog", "monkey"};
        string string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7, string8, string9, string10;
        string1 = safeGetString(stringArray, 1);
        string2 = safeGetString(stringArray, 2);
        string3 = safeGetString(stringArray, 3);
        string4 = safeGetString(stringArray, 4);
        string5 = safeGetString(stringArray, 5);
        string6 = safeGetString(stringArray, 6);
        string7 = safeGetString(stringArray, 7);
        string8 = safeGetString(stringArray, 8);
        string9 = safeGetString(stringArray, 9);
        string10 = safeGetString(stringArray, 10);
        ltlInfo.Text = string1 + ", " + string1 + ", " + string2 + ", " + string3 + ", " + string4 + ", " + string5 + ", " + string6 + ", " + string7 + ", " + string8 + ", " + string9 + ", " + string10;
    }

    private string safeGetString(string[] stringArray, int index)
    {
        if (index < stringArray.Length)
        {
            return stringArray[index];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var temp = (string[])array.Clone();
Array.Resize<string>(ref temp, NewSize);
```

Comment: How will the above code work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do so, just create a new array of string, something like this:

```
var s = yourStringArray.Select((x,i)=>i>6 ? "" : x).ToArray();
//s[7] == s[8] == s[9] = ""     //Notice the Zero-based index of string array
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty array to hold the strings you want and copy to it. Any remaining space will have `null` references:

```
string[] oldArr = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
string[] newArr = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < oldArr.Length; i++)
{
     newArr[i] = oldArr[i];
}
```

`newArr` now has:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- null
- null
- null

Comment: Again this is an array. I would rather need these values in different strings

Comment: The values **are** in different strings??

Comment: No The values are in an array. I now need them in different strings.

Comment: **The values are in different strings which are contained in the array**. That they are stored in an array doesn't change the fact that each value is still held by a different string. You can access each of these strings by index - `newArr[0]` points to the first string in the collection. This is far more efficient than declaring the 10 strings explicitly.

Comment: But if I do not have a value in say newarr[7] which I do not know right at the begining..it throws an exception

Comment: Then use a `List<T>` or check that the element is not null?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
{
  if(i<arr.length)
   new_arr[i]=arr[i];
  else
   new_arr[i]=null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
List<string> DoFoo(string [] input, int expectedOutputSize, string defaultValue)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    result.AddRange(input);

    while(result.Count < expectedOutputSize)
    {
        result.Add(defaultValue);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And usage

```
string[] input = new[] {"string1", "string2"};
var output = DoFoo(input, 10, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass these values into 10 different strings

you can loop like this

```
for(int i=0;i<strArray.Length;i++)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strArray[i]))
    {
          //do your work
    }
}
```

Comment: It says .is null or empty not a valid parameter for string